# why am i unable to play audio file

Tags: java, audio, vlc

hey there I am using this command

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\ProgramFiles\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", videopath);
Process start = pb.start();
```

it can play video but unable to play audio file.
The file by itself can be played on vlc externaly.

Comment: Use cntrl+k to format your code.

Comment: Are you sure your paths are well - on windows you should use `/` or ``\\`` in the strings.

Comment: it worked with video with \\

Comment: it's working fine with video but i have no idea why the audio is not working

Comment: Unless you explicitly want to control the application that opens a file, java.awt.Desktop has a nice method "open(File)" which will just open the file using the default system association. May be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

all i had to do was play them on windows media player instead of VLC